# What's the difference between those two commands in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose you have:

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
```

#### Statement 1:

```
output = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(input, 10, weights_initializer = tf.zeros_initializer, biases_initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
```

#### Statement 2:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
output = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
```

Does output in both statements return the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent. Statement 1 also adds [an activation function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/27711108b5fce2e1692f9440631a183b3808fa01/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L1329).

If you set `activation=None`, then they are equal.